# What's "the" physical explanation of hysteresis in ferrimagnetic materials?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, material-science

I am wondering what is "the" or "a" physical explanation of hysteresis in ferrimagnetic materials.

From what I've read in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_hysteresis) and [Cullity's book](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471477419.html), there is a simple physical explanation for ferr**o**magnetic materials's hysteresis while it is said that ferr**i**magnetic materials also exhibit hysteresis while the physical explanation is omitted. Basically a ferromagnetic material contains domains where the moments of atoms point roughly in the same direction, but the domains's moments point in random directions so that at first the material has no net magnetization. When a magnetic field is applied, the domain walls move so that the net magnetic moment of the whole material increases and tends to point in the same direction than the applied field. But this can't hold true for any value of applied field, indeed at some point the walls have almost vanished (or can't move anymore due to impurities, etc.). Then what happens is that the magnetization of the domain(s) rotates toward the applied field, eventually reaching the saturation magnetization for some value of the applied field from which the magnetization of the material almost doesn't increase even though the applied field continues to increase.

But in the case of ferr**i**magnetic materals, there is no magnetic domains. Instead, at a microscopic level (at least in ferrites) there are A and B sites which form A and B alternating sublattices. Where the magnetic moments of the A and B sublattices are different, hence the material showing a non zero magnetization even in the absence of applied field. I can't seem to be able to apply any of the 2 mechanisms (walls motion and rotation) that makes a ferrogmatic material display hysteresis. Hence my title question.

Comment: I may have forgotten something, but why do two correlated sub lattices exclude domains?  Take every pair of molecule A and molecule B and regard them as a whole and you're back to a ferromagnet

Comment: I think that the sublattices extend to the whole crystal unlike magnetic domains in a ferromagnet. "ferrimagnet magnetic domain" doesn't returna anything either...

Comment: That sounds like "citation needed"(tm). Wiki mentions magnetic domains in ferromagnets [...] and ferrimagnets like ferrite in the "Magnetic domain" page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, apparently I hadn't read carefully that wikipedia's article. Feel free to write an answer.

Comment: Nah, I don't feel like doing a two-line answer. If you're satisfied by it, you're welcome to self-answer your question.